# Expected value of a strange PMF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

Say we have a PMF defined as $p_X(x)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{x^2} $.

Our expected value $E[X]=\sum_{x=1}^\infty x\frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Can we merely simplify this to be $E[X]=\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{6}{\pi^2x}$? How else could we define $E[X]$?

Comment: Your work is fine; to conclude, note that the last series you have written is divergent, so the expectation does not exist. This PMF has similar decay as the PDF of the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), which also does not have a finite expectation.

Comment: What is the domain of the function? The domain is always an integral part of the function.

Comment: Domain seems to be 1 through $\infty:$ In R, sum of first 10,000 terms of PMF is `x = 1:10000; (6/pi^2)*sum(x^-2)`, which computes to 0.9999392. Sum converges slowly. Not surprising that expectation diverges as per @angryavian. // What specific question prompted this post: Asked to compute expectation? Asked whether expectation exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is due to the well known  [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) solved by Euler in his 20's. The PMF in question is the scaled version of this famous infinite series.

As indicated by the comment by @angryavian, this is the discrete analogue of the Cauchy distribution.

\begin{align} 
E[X] & =\sum_{x=1}^\infty x\frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{x^2} \\
& = \frac{6}{\pi^2} \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x} 
\end{align}

which is a constant times the divergent harmonic series and as such the $EX$ does not exist.